# Safari slow performance when playing audio over itself multiple times in a short time

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webkit, html5-audio

I'm trying to play a sound over itself on keydown.
In order to do so, I saw the solution is to clone the sound and play the new instance instead:

```
var promise = sound.cloneNode(true).play();
```

Reproduction online:
https://jsfiddle.net/alvarotrigo/up4c6m95/13/

This seems to be working fine in Chrome and Firefox. However in Safari this results in bad performance.

Try typing very fast with both hands to reproduce the error.

Note I added a gif image that lags when typing very quickly. 
This can of course be noted as well on the Safari dev tools as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

Whole code here:

```
var sound = new Audio('https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3');

document.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);


function playSound() {
  //in order to play the same sound over itself
  var promise = sound.cloneNode(true).play();

  //we just dont want to show the console error when autoplay is disabled :)
  if (typeof promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(function() {
      // Autoplay started!
    }).catch(function(error) {
      //error
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Safari puts a request every time for the audio file being played, while on the other hand it's not the case for Firefox and Chrome as they tend to load it only once.

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad) ... no data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method
>   is triggered by user action.

I don't think you can get around the slow performance resulting in putting out a request on each keydown.

Comment: How do other html 5 games deal with it then?

Comment: @Alvaro I'm sharing my maybe limited knowledge about the subject, I'm no HTML5 expert, I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable to answer your question :-)

Comment: I'm not an expert either but I suppose many other HTML5 games use https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js which solves a lot of quirks related to audio.

Comment: @borisdiakur or phaser ;) https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser